# How to clone a entity with its attached fields?

Tags: entities

I am trying to create a entity with few bundles. I have used **EntityDefaultUIController** as admin UI callback. This provides me with few default functions such as clone, import and export. The problem is when I try to clone or export the entity. It does not export or clone the fields attached to it. Has anyone faced similar issues. I traced back the issue to **entity_ui_get_form** function which does not have any function related to getting the field information. How could I clone entity with its fields attached to it?

Kindly help me figure this out.

Comment: as I understand, more accurate title should be "How to clone an entity type...". As I understand, you would need to clone entity type, not entities (instances of entity type)?

Answer (score 1):

A recent module called [Replicate](https://drupal.org/project/replicate) provides an API to easily clone any entity, including of course its fields and references.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue open on drupal.org for cloning fields along with the entity.  There's also an RTBC patch - see https://www.drupal.org/node/1513812.  The patch to use is number 23 (https://www.drupal.org/node/1513812#comment-7800593).